# NLog does not write to database in console application

Tags: c#, console-application, nlog

I have a simple console application:

```
class Program
{
    private static ILogger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _logger.Info($"Выполнено в {DateTime.Now}");
    }
}
```

I installed NuGet packages

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="NLog" version="4.7.6" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="NLog.Extended" version="4.6.8" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

And configured params in `app.config`:

Register NLog section

```
<configSections>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" />
</configSections>
```

Connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="QtContext" 
         connectionString="data source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=qtrdb_azure_copy;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Configured NLog section

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
        <target name="database" xsi:type="Database">
            <connectionStringName>QtContext</connectionStringName>
            <commandText> insert into dbo.NLOG (Logged,Level,Message) values (@Logged,@Level,@Message);</commandText>
            <parameter name="@Logged" layout="${date:format=yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fff}" />
            <parameter name="@Level" layout="${level}" />
            <parameter name="@Message" layout="${message}" />
        </target>
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" writeTo="database" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

NLog does not write to messages to the database table ...

Comment: Do you get any errors? Have you tried adding a different logging target and logging to it (to try to isolate the error)?

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting The usual problem is forgetting to copy the NLog.config to output-folder. The other problem is people using the broken nuget-package NLog.config - https://nuget.org/packages/NLog.Config But if not those two issues then activate NLog InternalLogger and check for warnings and errors.